# Parent div with height: 100% doesn't work

Tags: css, height

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [CSS - 100% height doesn’t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789835/css-100-height-doesnt-work)

I have 3 `div`s, the `div-1` is a background and `div-2` and `div-3` are two containers (one for text and one for photo).

```css
#div-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#div-2 {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

#div-3 {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  <div id="div-2"></div>
  <div id="div-3"></div>
</div>
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Why `height: 100%` doesn't work?

Comment: try this: `html,body{height:100%;}` The height of these elements is automatic.

Comment: This worked for me. Looking at the standard default css rules, I see no reason for these elements to have auto height. Oh, I guess because html has no parent its 100% height is zero? Strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can work

```
<div id="div-1">
    <div id="div-2"></div>
    <div id="div-3"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 4):

The height of #div-1 is 100% but 100% of nothing, as it relies on the parent tags height I believe. Try setting your body to 100% height in css.

Comment: That doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/qecd1r3y/
100vh does.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `height: 100%;` in `#div-1` and add `position: absolute;`. It will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add clear flow after you applying floating properties to elements, more about it here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html