# textarea text is not showing and footer bug

Tags: database

I have a page showPages.php which shows the list of pages with page id and page title. when one of them is clicked, it goes to editPages.php. In editPages.php, two (input tag) field is showing correctly but two textarea field's text is not showing which is very annoying. 
I am extracting all data in a row with the help of page id.

Parsed text is showing in "View-source" or crome's web developer console. I have also checked for background color and text color. But unable to solve. Even when i write something in textarea, is updating after click the update button but text is not showing in textarea field.

I have provided editPages.php code and snapshot here with footer problem details.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PWvNSF2tiCMx6Os6uXulpTHzBbhd98wW9dtgbUGE-hs/edit

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you set the value of textarea

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="page_meta"class="field size1">
     <?php echo $row['page_meta_desc'];?>
</textarea>
```

not

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="page_meta"class="field size1" value="<?php echo $row['page_meta_desc'];?>"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is the textarea visible on page? Does <?php echo $row['page_meta_desc'];?> return any result? see example http://fiddle.jshell.net/6Qx6b/

Comment: okay. problem solved. Now footer position problem.anyone can help?

Comment: Without seeing the css and html structure it going to be difficult to fix.. if you are using 'floot:left/right' then you will need to do a <div style="clear:both"></div> before the footer section http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: hello R S, i have added info for footer problem.Take a look and reply

Comment: Your issue have something to do with the way you are using height:100% see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789835/css-100-height-doesnt-work ... try removing "position: absolute;bottom:0;" and make something like #container{min-height:700px}.. A design with the footer the way it is always a little tricky... what I would recommend is moving the footer into the content div (similarly to 'edit page') see the way they do this design http://www.magento-mall.com/checkout/cart/  .. body alway have a fix min height