# <div> take up all height of parent

Tags: html, css

I have two side-by-side `<div>` blocks that are both contained in a larger `<div>` block. I'd like the smaller of the two child `<div>` blocks to take up all remaining vertical space of the parent block, without actually knowing the height of the parent.

Is this possible to do without any Javascript?

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/5J8Em/2/ I'd like the red `<div>` to be just as tall as the blue one.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: What I'm saying is: This can easily be done using Javascript...but I'm looking for a pure CSS method.

Comment: @Jesse. Then why did you tag the question with `javascript` tag...?

Comment: @jesse: And I was saying the `javascript` tag was inappropriate in that case. Someone's removed it for you, which is probably for the best.

Comment: See this post for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789835/css-100-height-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `display:table;` for parent element and `display: table-cell;` for children:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        hello world 
    </div>
    <div id="c">
        hello world hello world hello world 
        hello world hello world hello world 
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#a {
     background-color:rgb(100,100,100);      
     width:200px; 
     display:table;
}

#b {
     background-color:red; 
     vertical-align:top;
     display: table-cell;
}

#c {
     background-color:blue;   
     width:100px;
     word-wrap:break-word;   
     display: table-cell;    
}
```

Here is the **[jsFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/5J8Em/13/) demo**