# <li> will not take 100% height of the parent <ul>

Tags: html, css, height

I have a `<ul>` with several `<li>` items in it all in a single row. The `<li>` has a nested `<span>` and an `<img>`. The `<img>` height is all the same across all items. But the `<span>` items contain text which can span on a single line or two lines (depends on text).

I have tried appying `display:block`, `float:left`, `height:100%`, and few other suggestions I found, but the shorter `<li>` items will not take the same height as the taller `<li>` items. So I am left with a space below the shorter `<li>` items. 
Anyone has any suggestions on this?

Comment: Can yo ushow us an example of the html/css?

Comment: Please use jsfiddle.net to create a demo

Comment: Set up a Fiddle for this, and it will be easier for people to help you : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Did you try `height:150px` or whatever the max anticipated height will be?

Comment: Hello, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KingsInnerSoul/DEnwQ/16/ . You can see how two of the <li> items do nto span the entire heignt. How can I make it so? @Sable, I do nto want to hard code the height because the span text length is unknown for each item.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case, when you set `height:100%` it isn't inheriting any height from its parent. If you want the list items to have 100% height of the div #wrapper, then you should set the ul's height to 100% and set a height on the div #wrapper in pixels or em's:

http://jsfiddle.net/SF9Za/1/

```css
#wrapper {
  background: transparent;
  width: 350px;
  color: white;
  height: 250px;
}
#wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

If you'd rather have it stretch to the full height of the browser window, then you need to set the height of HTML, body in your CSS to 100%, and then all of the elements down to the li (HTML, body, div#wrapper, ul. list, and li) must have 100% height:

http://jsfiddle.net/YdGra/

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  background: transparent;
  width: 350px;
  color: white;
  height:100%;
}
#wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: green;
  height:100%;
}
```

Here are some other links that you might want to check out that talk about this:

- [CSS 100% height layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158975/css-100-height-layout)
- [Setting height: 100% on my label element doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789835/css-100-height-doesnt-work)
- http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Comment: Is there another way to get the 100%? As I am still will be hardcoding the total height. Is there a way to get the total height from the browser? I mean the browser allocates space for each `<li>` and eventually wraps the `<ul>` height. So cant we somehow "steal" that height value?

Comment: The only other way I know of is to use javascript to get the height: http://jsfiddle.net/pDW5q/ And here is an example with your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4peG/

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix is to add `display:table` on your ul element. The hieght will align with the content.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it fix if you change `list-style-position` of the container ul

Comment: Just tried inside and outside and it does not help. Thanks though