# Force two <li> elements to have same height

Tags: css, html-lists

I have two `<li>` elements with a different content (different length texts), but for design reasons they should have the same height. Also, their width is relative, so I do not know the total height. Is there a way to set the height of both `<li>` elements to that of the largest `<li>` using CSS?

Jsfiddle: [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/vxnwzwzs/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>caption 1</h2>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>caption 2</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `float: left;` and `display: inline-block;` together don't make a whole lotta sense

Comment: Have you tried specifiying the height in css to "x" px and `overflow: hidden` in `li`?

Comment: I cannot specify the height because the width of each list item is relative to the main view port (35% in my case).

Comment: You mean you want the height to change depending on the width?

Comment: Yes, of course, that is the standard behavior. But I want the heights to be the same as well. The answer below using `display: flex` does exactly that.

Comment: I think you mean you want to set the height of all li = largest li height, stickers solution in that case is perfect.

Comment: Yes, this is obviously true. It hardly makes sense to have the two li's assume the height of the shortest height, does it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<li> will not take 100% height of the parent <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321657/li-will-not-take-100-height-of-the-parent-ul)

Comment: I added the 'relative width' remark in the question, which makes it distinct from the possible duplicate.

Comment: @Bricky Can you please remove the 'possible duplicate' tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I believe is using flexbox.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 35%;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>caption 1</h2>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>caption 2</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```