# the content (webview) doesnt fill the app window

Tags: javascript, css, webview, electron

I'm trying out the electron to create a standalone version of the website, I have this main.js (excerpt)

```
function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        "min-width": 800,
        "min-height": 500,
        resize: true,
        "use-content-size": true
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    // Set Window Resizable
    mainWindow.isResizable(true);

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}
```

then index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #6e6e6e;
        }
        webview {
            display: block;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <webview src="build/index.html" disablewebsecurity></webview>
</body>

</html>
```

unfortunately the content (webview) is not resized to fill available space, it has full width but height remains at 150px, when I manually set different size in the inspector panel then it adjusts. How can I tell webview that it should take full space? percentage doesnt work ie.

```
webview {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

I have added following code to the `index.html`

```
<script>
    function onResize() {
        var height = document.body.clientHeight;
        var width = document.body.clientWidth;
        console.log("onResize", arguments, width, height);
    }
    addEventListener('resize', onResize);

</script>
```

Which outputs following results (height always 150!)

```
onResize [Event] 216 150
index.html:27 onResize [Event] 216 150
index.html:27 onResize [Event] 1096 150
index.html:27 onResize [Event] 1096 150
index.html:27 onResize [Event] 1096 150
index.html:27 onResize [Event]                1080 150
        0: Event
            bubbles: true
            cancelBubble: false
            cancelable: false
            currentTarget: null
            defaultPrevented: fals
            eeventPhase: 0
            isTrusted: false
            isTrusted: false
            newHeight: 150
            newWidth: 1080
            path: Array[5]
            returnValue: true
            srcElement: webview
            target: webview
            timeStamp: 1453905541457
            type: "resize"__proto__: Event
            callee: onResize()
            length: 1
            Symbol(Symbol.iterator): values()
            __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've set the height of the `webview` to `100%`, but didn't set an explicit height for the parent (in this case the `body`). Giving the `body` and explicit size should fix your problem:

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

See also:

- [Setting height: 100% on my label element doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789835/setting-height-100-on-my-label-element-doesnt-work)
- [Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)