# Two equal 50% width column full height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create 2 columns, each occupying width of 50%. I need the column height to stretch to the full height of the screen, even when empty, so I can display the backfround color. I tried adding position: absolute but am having mixed results where only one column appears

My HTML

```
.lcolmn {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
.rcolmn {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
.wrapper {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="lcolmn">
       <div class="lcontent"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="rcolmn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wrapper is your css is targeting classes, not ids as in your html. You should change your html ids to classes

Comment: `height: 100vh;` and then visit a pub.

Comment: try to use `vh` instead of  `%`

Comment: @Charlie S vh has issues in safari

Comment: downvoted question and upvoted comments, the downvote only so that you learn the (very basic) difference between styling divs by id and class properly through CSS code (forever!). You can do this many different ways, 100vh is a little bit too modern for my liking, but coolness outweighs any drawback

Comment: I have fixed the ID to Class for wrapper

Comment: @Jeffrey-Humanized issue isn't even that the wrapper in his css is targetting classes(even though he should learn the difference). Since he has % on height and there is no content in the divs, it wont show anything.

Comment: @Jeffrey-Humanized Yeah downvote people for not knowng something. Good going there. Upvoted the question

Comment: vh is currently supported in Safari 10 and above http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: 'height: 100%' will work if the container has a set height. Set height of the parent container around .wrapper divs. Set the container to 100vh to get the full effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is solution, HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="lcolmn">

  </div>
  <div class="rcolmn">

  </div>
</div>
```

and SASS:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
  height:100%;
  .lcolmn,
  .rcolmn {
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
  }
  .lcolmn {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .rcolmn {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Here you can check example: https://jsfiddle.net/vladavip88/1cd7rq0f/

Comment: Thanks I would use your code. I much simpler as I would be using javascript to adjust the width

Answer (score 5):

Here's the proper solution, without `vh` and optimized CSS:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left
}

#lcolumn {
  background-color: red;
}

#rcolumn {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="column" id="lcolumn">
  <div class="lcontect"></div>
</div>
<div class="column" id="rcolumn"></div>
```

Comment: good solution @Chris G. Never knew that setting the height 100% would work for child divs as long as you specified the html height to be 100%

Comment: Thanks alot, exactly what I needed

Comment: @Joseph Did you accidentally accept the other answer as best?

Comment: I need jquery to adjust the width of lcolumn and rcolumn, give them different width ratios. That would be a problem with your html structure. Your code is right, apart from this issue which is due to me

Comment: @Joseph No it wouldn't. `$("#lcolumn").css("width", "30%");
$("#rcolumn").css("width", "70%");` works fine. Setting IDs will override the `.column` rule.

Comment: Actually think your right. am working on the javascript now, will test your code on it.

Comment: @Joseph Did you test it?

Answer (score 1):

The elements inside the wrapper class current have no set height given. Height 100% doesn't work in CSS (see this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789845/4912604)

What does work thought is the CSS tag "vh" or "view height". Add this to the lcolumn and rcolmn classes

```
.lcolmn {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
}
.rcolmn {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/iamnottony/1jw4e256/

Comment: I dont want to use vh due to safari issues

Comment: ahhhh ok, i'll leave this answer just incase some else stumbles across and vh is an acceptable solution for them

Answer (score 0):

Please start to use `box-sizing: border-box`.
Just set it to *, *::after, *::before. so in css:

```
*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left
}

#lcolumn {
  background-color: red;
}

#rcolumn {
  background-color: blue;
}
```